# Square FloatingActionButton with Android Design Library

Tags: android, android-design-library

The new android design library provides the `android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton` to make it easier to implement a floating action button.

But the button is **always** a circle.

I received from the company designer a square floating button concept, but I can't find any reference to change the background of the `android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton` to have a square background.

Note: If I use a custom custom drawable the background still have the circle, like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/button_filter"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/appbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />
```

[image]

I try to use a simple `Button`, but it seems to break the toolbar size when it was collapsed:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_filter"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/appbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />
```

[image]

Is possible to have a square button using the `FloatingActionButton` **with the new Android Design Library?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, using use the attribute `app:borderWidth="0dp"` in the `FloatingActionButton` solved the problem.

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/button_filter"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/appbar"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the "android:background", look at the template below and notice the "app:backgroundTint", use it as template and it should work:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/your_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/floating_button_margin_bottom"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/floating_button_margin_right"
        app:elevation="@dimen/floating_button_elevation"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:rippleColor="@color/your_ripple_color"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/your_bg_color" />
```