# How do I use a floating action button as a square?

Tags: android, floating-action-button, material-components-android, material-components, android-shapedrawable

There are tons of SO threads saying their button is appearing as a square do to a bug

[Floating Action Button with square shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31202622/floating-action-button-with-square-shape/31667546)

[Square FloatingActionButton with Android Design Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30715510/square-floatingactionbutton-with-android-design-library)

[Floating Action Button appearing as a square](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50587736/floating-action-button-appearing-as-a-square)

However my goal is to USE a square button. How would I change the `circle floating action button` into a square one?

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
        android:backgroundTint="@color/standardBlue"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_3d_model"/>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it with the official `FloatingActionButton` in the Material Components Library using the **`shapeAppearanceOverlay`** attribute.

Just use:

```
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/fab_square"
```

with

```
<style name="fab_square" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">0dp</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**FloatingActionButton** does not provide `shapes` other than `rounded` see this [Request: allow to set the shape of FAB](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/133389626)

Yet there are many ways other than this to do But one which I personally recommend is using [customFloatingActionButton](https://github.com/robertlevonyan/customFloatingActionButton) library by `robertlevonyan`, It is easy to use and customizable.

**Square Shape**

Add the following line of code to your module(app) level Gradle file

```
implementation 'com.robertlevonyan.view:CustomFloatingActionButton:3.0.1'
```

Now add the following code to **activity_main.xml**

```
<com.robertlevonyan.views.customfloatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
       android:id="@+id/custom_fab"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="bottom|end" />
```

> You can customize it in XML too by adding `app:fabType="square"` but I
> prefer MainActivity.java

Then customize `floatingactionbutton` in `MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        floatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.custom_fab);

        floatingActionButton.setFabType(FabType.FAB_TYPE_SQUARE); //set button type to square
        floatingActionButton.setFabIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_baseline_add_btn_24, null));

    }
}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: It is not correct. The official FAB supports shaping with the `ShapeAppearanceModel` and you can define a custom `CornerTreatment` not only a `RoundedCornerTreatment` or `CutCornerTreatment`. In this case a `RoundedCornerTreatment` is enough, just use `0dp` as you can check in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use this library [customFloatingActionButton](https://github.com/robertlevonyan/customFloatingActionButton) by Robertlevonyan.

```
<com.robertlevonyan.examples.customfloatingactionbutton.view.FloatingLayout
        android:id="@+id/floating_layout"
        app:fabType="square"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
```